# group values in rows together and assign a interger value to them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, where-clause

Hi I have dataframe that looks like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | X | 10 | 1a |
| FH | Y | 15 | 4h |
| KY | Z | 20 | 6f |
| DA | X | 10 | 1a |

I want to create a new column where an interger (starting from 1/0) is assigned to all rows that have same value in column B,C,D

for eg : row1,4 will be same integer in column 'Val' that is created.

Output should look something like this

| A | B | C | D | Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | X | 10 | 1a | 1 |
| FH | Y | 15 | 4h | 2 |
| KY | Z | 20 | 6f | 3 |
| DA | X | 10 | 1a | 1 |

Comment: the column Val can be random alphanumeric too but something that is unique

Comment: Please insert the dataframe as code, not as an image

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.factorize` with a `frozenset`

```
df['Val'] = pd.factorize(df[['B', 'C', 'D']].apply(frozenset, axis=1))[0] + 1
print(df)

# Output
    A  B   C   D  Val
0  AB  X  10  1a    1
1  FH  Y  15  4h    2
2  KY  Z  20  6f    3
3  DA  X  10  1a    1
```

Comment: nice answer! you were right cumcount was the wrong way to go

Comment: @HK1. Does it solve your problem?